# getApplicationContext() in AppCompatActivity (appcompatv7)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an android project with several packages, when I try to compile it I get

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/w3c/dom/Attr.class
```

I found on the internet a solution that implies adding the below rule, but when I add it

```
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

I can not use getApplicationContext() method anymore.

My MainActivity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //The below method is the one I can not use.
        context = getApplicationContext();
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of excluding the support v4 from appcompat (which is necessary) try finding the following jar file: libs/android-support-v4.jar somewhere in your project and delete it.

Comment: please to all your gradle file

Comment: really I was frustrated with that issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must update your library support in the SDK manager.

Comment: @ReazMurshed How does this not attempt to provide an answer?